# Running python script in VSCode produces truncated output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

## Steps to reproduce:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(0,100000):
    my_list.append(i)
print(my_list)
```

Running this (Run-> Run without debugger [or with it]) produces a truncated output on my VSCode in version 1.55 with up to date python extension (v2020.10.332292344) and python 3.9.4.

*"Run Python File in Terminal"* (via command palette) shows the whole output correctly (but with this the script's working directory isn't the script's directory; my original problem was about reading a csv file where i noticed said problem).

(I already set `Python › Data Science: Text Output Limit` to 0).

So how to fix this issue?

Comment: that is how the variable viewer is coded in the debugger, do you really need to look at all elements during debugging?

Comment: @SearchSpace -Do you mean that when the code is debugged in the "Python Debug Console", the data it displays is incomplete (only the data from 0 to1978 is displayed)?

Comment: @rioV8 Even on "Run without debugger" ( ctrl + F5) this behaviour happens. And yes,  i need to see the whole Output.

Comment: @JillCheng Even if I use "Run without debugger" (ctrl +F5), it's shown in the terminal (and there in "Python Debug Console"). Yes, you predicted the result correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the information you provided, I reproduced the problem and I have submitted it. You could follow the progress of this link: [VS Code's debug console cannot display complete data.](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/582)

Comment: Yeah, I already saw (I'm the first commenter there :) ). I will mark this as the answer, if this leads to the solution. A sub-question: Why does "Run without debugger" (ctrl +F5) run in "Python Debug Console" at all?

Comment: @SearchSpace -You could refer to this link: [Run mode in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode).